# Fetch data from cassandra by portion

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

In cassandra db, I have a table with 10 millions rows. If I use normal select query, I can only have 1 connection to cassandra to fetch data. Is it possible to do select query with row number ?

```
E.g. Select * from abc where row = x to row = y ?
```

So I can have 10 different threads, so each of them will be responsible to fetch 1 million rows. If this is possible, should I have number of threads equal to the number of nodes I have in my cluster?

I'm connecting to my cassandra cluster by using java datastax driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do select query with row number ?

No, but it is possible to execute a range query based on the hashed token value of your partition key.

Let's say that you have a six node cluster.  The Murmur3 primary token ranges for a 6 node cluster look like this:

```
node   start range              end range
1)     9223372036854775808 to  -9223372036854775808
2)    -9223372036854775807 to  -5534023222112865485
3)    -5534023222112865484 to  -1844674407370955162
4)    -1844674407370955161 to   1844674407370955161
5)     1844674407370955162 to   5534023222112865484
6)     5534023222112865485 to   9223372036854775807
```

If I have a table called `abc` with a partition key of `pkey`, and wanted to query all rows for that table on node 2, my query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM abc
  WHERE token(pkey) >   9223372036854775808
    AND token(pkey) <= -5534023222112865485;
```

If an entire row's worth is too many (and I'm guessing that it will be), you can work on bisecting your token range until the number of rows becomes manageable.  Remember, selecting 10 million rows isn't something that Cassandra was designed to be particularly good at, so it might take a few tries.

As for thread count, that may also take some trial and error.  But one thread per node sounds like a reasonable starting point.